# I want my article in a particular publication (online) to be brought down. What are the solutions. Please let me know

Tags: publications

I want my article in a particular publication (online) to be brought down in a journal, because it was published by one of my ex-teachers w/o my consent. What are the plausible solutions. Please let me know.

Comment: Contact the editor in the first instance. You say "my article", so you wrote it and the ex-teacher published it? Or you wrote it together and you agreed to publish, but now want to retract?

Comment: If this is in the US, you can file a [DMCA complaint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act) with the school's legal department. If they don't have permission, they can't publish it. OTOH, it's possible they actually *do* have permission, depending on what you signed while in school

Comment: Please clarify if your name is on the article.

Comment: Please explain why you think that your consent should have been necessary to publish the article. Did you write the article with your teacher? Did you contribute to the research? Without more information, it is difficult to determine whether you have a legitimate grievance and what the best course of action might be.

Comment: Are you listed as an author?